# Mumbai Airport inter Terminal transport

Tags: airports, mumbai, bom

Is there any airport transport to travel from Mumbai Airport Terminal 1 (International) to the Terminal 2 to catch the domestic connecting flight?

Answer (score 1):

There is a transportation service:

> **T1B to T2: Prices Rs.245 for a Sedan. Rs.700 for a SUV.** 
>   T2 to T1B: Prices Rs.230 for a Sedan. Rs.750 for a SUV.
>
> The counters to buy the ticket are located:
>   **T1B: Arrivals. Phone: 8767350021**.
>
> T2: Level 2, International Arrivals. Phone: (022) 65882672

([Airport Website](https://www.mumbaiairport.com/transport.php))